# blazor how to pass the variable value in the component to the MainLayout component

Tags: blazor

I created a project using the blazor server template that comes with vs 2019, how do I pass the currentCount property value in the Counter.razor component to a MainLayout.razor component?

And when the page is loaded, the currentCount value passed in the Mainlayout component is the same as the currentCount value in the Counter component. And when the currentCount value changes, the currentCount value in Mainlayout will also change.

MainLayout.razor:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
            <LoginDisplay />
        </div>
        <div class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Counter.razor

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be with a state service.

Add a class to your project
`MainLayoutState.cs`

```
public class MainLayoutState
{
    int currentCount;
    public int CurrentCount
    {
        get => currentCount;
        set
        {
            if (currentCount == value) return;
            currentCount = value;
            CurrentCountChanged?.Invoke(this, value);
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler<int> CurrentCountChanged;
}
```

Update `Startup.cs` so it can be injected.

```
services.AddScoped<MainLayoutState>();
```

Use it in both the layout and the counter razor components.

`MainLayout.razor`

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@implements IDisposable
@inject MainLayoutState LayoutState
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <LoginDisplay /> @LayoutState.CurrentCount
        </div>

        <div class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => LayoutState.CurrentCountChanged += CountChanged;

    void CountChanged(object sender, int e) => StateHasChanged();

    public void Dispose() => LayoutState.CurrentCountChanged -= CountChanged;
}
```

Change the code block in `Counter.razor`

```
@code {

    int CurrentCount { 
        get => LayoutState.CurrentCount; 
        set => LayoutState.CurrentCount = value; }

    [Inject]
    MainLayoutState LayoutState { get; set; }

    void IncrementCount()
    {
        CurrentCount++;
    }

}
```

Comment: This seems to be affecting global state, as if you only have one instance of MainLayout.  But each page could have a new copy of the state to use in its own instance of the main layout.

Comment: @ChrisBordeman If that is required use a factory / dictionary key arrangement for instances of state. I would create a factory service to manage that.

Comment: nice solution but may this cause any memory leak as it will keep the page not disposed until the entire websiteis closed or disposed

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for cascading parameters. Cascading values and parameters are a way to pass a value from a component to all of its descendants without having to use traditional component parameters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Example for origin of the cascading value will cascade to contained components.

```cs
<CascadingValue Value="@CurrentCount">
 @Body
</CascadingValue>

@code{
   int CurrentCount = 5;
}
```

The inner component should then decorate its property as following.

```cs
[CascadingParameter] int CurrentCount { get; set; }
```

Comment: Cascading Parameters are the opposite of what he's asking for.  He wants to pass UP from the page to the master, not cascade down to page.  I think the only clean solution is to simply move the NavLink out of the master page and set its properties directly on each page.  I've seen the AppState approach, too, but that assumes a single state for each page.

Comment: like Chris said, you understood his question wrong but even if the question was like that, can you explain how to use cascading parameter on navigation component? is this approach not only for child components? obviously the Counter.razor is defining a navigation and it is routed component not  child component.